# How to add new line to the hover label in python plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, mpld3

I want to add the text with new line when specific point is hovered in the plot.For example if A point is hovered then the hovered label will display text like this,
text1
text2
text3
Below is draw_plot function snippet:

```
   def draw_plot(ue_info,selected_parm):

            rp_x = [-1.0,0.0,1.0,-1.0,0.0,1.0,-1.0,0.0,1.0,-1.0,0.0,1.0]
            rp_y = [1.5,1.5,1.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,-0.5,-0.5,-0.5,-1.5,-1.5,-1.5]
            Cluster = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1,1,1])

            fig = plt.figure()
            ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
            scatter = ax.scatter(rp_x,rp_y,c=Cluster,s=50)
            fig.patch.set_visible(False)
            ax.axis('off')
            ax.set_autoscale_on(False)

            ue_offset  = 0.2

            for ue in ue_info:
                    try:
                            i = rand.uniform(rp_x[int(ue_info[ue]["pr_rp_id"])]-ue_offset,rp_x[int(ue_info[ue]["pr_rp_id"])]+ue_offset)
                            j = rand.uniform(rp_y[int(ue_info[ue]["pr_rp_id"])]-ue_offset,rp_y[int(ue_info[ue]["pr_rp_id"])]+ue_offset)
                            if float(ue_info[ue][selected_parm]) < 20.0:
                                    ues = ax.scatter(i,j,s=50,c='green',marker='+')
                            if float(ue_info[ue][selected_parm]) < 21.0:
                                    ues = ax.scatter(i,j,s=50,c='orange',marker='+')
                            else:
                                    ues = ax.scatter(i,j,s=50,c='red',marker='+')
                            ueLabel = "UE:"+ue +"\n" +" pr_rp_id:"+ ue_info[ue]["pr_rp_id"]
                            tooltip = mpld3.plugins.PointLabelTooltip(ues,labels=[ueLabel])
                            mpld3.plugins.connect(fig, tooltip)
                    except:
                            print "One of the UE is removed while drawing the plot..."

            tooltip = mpld3.plugins.PointLabelTooltip(scatter)
            mpld3.plugins.connect(fig, tooltip)

            plt.text(-1.0, 1.7, "RP0", fontsize=8)
            plt.text(0.0, 1.7, "RP1", fontsize=8)
            plt.text(1.0, 1.7, "RP2", fontsize=8)
            plt.text(-1.0, 0.7, "RP3", fontsize=8)
            plt.text(0.0, 0.7, "RP4", fontsize=8)
            plt.text(1.0, 0.7, "RP5", fontsize=8)
            plt.text(-1.0,-0.3, "RP6", fontsize=8)
            plt.text(0.0, -0.3, "RP7", fontsize=8)
            plt.text(1.0, -0.3, "RP8", fontsize=8)
            plt.text(-1.0,-1.3, "RP9", fontsize=8)
            plt.text(0.0, -1.3, "RP10", fontsize=8)
            plt.text(1.0, -1.3, "RP11", fontsize=8)

            ax.set_ylim([-2,2])
            ax.set_xlim([-2,2])

            htmlGraph = mpld3.fig_to_html(fig)

            plt.close('all')
            return htmlGraph
```

The output when the point is hovered to specific point is as below:
[image]

So in above plot when the yellow "+" is hovered then it displays the hovered text in single line.But my desired output is:
UE:280
pr_rp_id:4

This is the part where I am adding the hover text with new line:

```
ueLabel = "UE:"+ue +"\n" +" pr_rp_id:"+ ue_info[ue]["pr_rp_id"]
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can produce new lines using PointHTMLTooltip instead of PointLabelTooltip:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpld3 import fig_to_html, plugins, display
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
points = ax.plot(range(10), 'o')

texts = ['<p><h5>{title1}</h3><p><h5>#{title2}</h3>'.format(
         title1='hello', title2=i) for i in range(10
        )]

text = plugins.PointHTMLTooltip(points[0], texts)
plugins.connect(fig, text)

fig_to_html(fig)
display()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi.It is working.But I face very strange issue.My plot is updating at interval of 2s.If I hover the cursor at some point then it will show me the text.This text does not go if my points are updated.So this hover text is not being cleared.Please help.

Comment: @spaceearth Post your problem as a new question. Describe all details required and provide the minimum number of lines of code reproducing the behavior you see.

Comment: I have added question for above problem.Please find it here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48146862/tooltips-show-on-hover-but-dont-disappear-using-mpld3